# 1084: Syntax error rightparen before function

Tags: actionscript-3

i have been learning action script 3 and now i get 2 errors i cant fix the main one being 1084: Syntax error rightparen before function

```
var blueS_1 = new blueS();

blueS_1.x = 50;
blueS_1.y = 50;

addChild(blueS_1);

blueS_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onclick


function onclick(e:MouseEvent);:void {
trace("click!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look some examples while learning. And when facing an issue, search for a solution and compare your code to examples.

You have couple very simple mistakes there.

Your code:

```
blueS_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onclick

function onclick(e:MouseEvent);:void {
    trace("click!");
}
```

Example:

```
blueS_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onclick);

function onclick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("click!");
}
```

So, missing `);` from event listener line  and extra `;` at function opener.

Comment: @pkaydeen If you use Flash/Animate, set also **File** -> **Publish settings** -> **Permit debugging** on. After this the error comes with line number and then you know which line triggers the error.